# Singleton Scope in a server

Tags: java, singleton

We have a Application server which runs a service and it is being invoked from web page. If there is a singleton object in the service, Will it be shared across all the instances of pages (for each service call)?

Comment: If you have a properly implemented singleton, there exists only a single object of that class in the JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how your singleton is implemented. In general (on a clean software design) the singleton runs during the runtime of your program. A web server is a program running in the background. If the singleton runs inside of this program than the singleton object will live over all instances of pages. If your Web server starts an other (java-)program otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The GoF Singleton pattern ensures that one and only one instance of a particular class is created per ClassLoader.